# Find the value of the fraction

Tags: number-theory

> What common fraction is equivalent to $$\frac{\dfrac{1}{1^3}+\dfrac{1}{3^3}+\dfrac{1}{5^3}+\dfrac{1}{7^3}+\cdots}{\dfrac{1}{1^3}+\dfrac{1}{2^3}+\dfrac{1}{3^3}+\dfrac{1}{4^3}+\cdots} \text{ ?}$$

I didn't see how to relate the numerator to the denominator. We can't find the value of the numerator and denominator easily it seems, so what else should we try?

Comment: As always, I believe in making things as simple as they really are, and I think my answer achieves that. $\qquad$

Comment: By standard manipulations, $$\frac{\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^s}}{\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}}=1-\frac{1}{2^s}$$ for any $s>1$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^3}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n)^3}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n-1)^3}=\zeta(3)$$
so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n-1)^3}=\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{8}\zeta(3)=\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)$$
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{1^3}+\dfrac{1}{3^3}+\dfrac{1}{5^3}+\dfrac{1}{7^3}+\cdots}{\dfrac{1}{1^3}+\dfrac{1}{2^3}+\dfrac{1}{3^3}+\dfrac{1}{4^3}+\cdots}=\frac{\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)}{\zeta(3)}=???$$

Comment: How is this true: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(2n-1)^3}=\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{8}\zeta(3)=\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)?$$

Comment: we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^3}=\zeta(3)$ which means zeta function at $x=3$

Comment: @user19405892 Because if $\underbrace{\sum \frac{1}{n^{3}}}_{\zeta(3)} = \underbrace{\sum \frac{1}{(2n)^{3}}}_{\frac{1}{8}\sum \frac{1}{n^{3}}} + \sum \frac{1}{(2n-1)^{3}}$, then the first term on the right hand side is just $\frac{1}{8} \zeta(3)$.  Solving for the second term on the right hand side gives $\sum \frac{1}{(2n-1)^{3}} = \zeta(3) - \frac{1}{8} \zeta(3)$.  And of course since $x - \frac{1}{8}x = \frac{7}{8}x$, we have $\zeta(3) - \frac{1}{8} \zeta(3) = \frac{7}{8} \zeta(3)$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
& \frac{\dfrac{1}{1^3}+\dfrac{1}{3^3}+\dfrac{1}{5^3}+\dfrac{1}{7^3}+\cdots}{\dfrac{1}{1^3}+\dfrac{1}{2^3}+\dfrac{1}{3^3}+\dfrac{1}{4^3}+\cdots} \\[12pt] = {} & \frac{ \left( \dfrac{1}{1^3}+\dfrac{1}{2^3}+\dfrac{1}{3^3}+\dfrac{1}{4^3}+\cdots\right) - \left( \dfrac 1 {2^3} + \dfrac 1 {4^3} + \dfrac 1 {6^3} + \cdots \right)}{\dfrac{1}{1^3}+\dfrac{1}{2^3}+\dfrac{1}{3^3}+\dfrac{1}{4^3}+ \cdots} \\[12pt]
 = {} & \frac{ \left( \dfrac{1}{1^3}+\dfrac{1}{2^3}+\dfrac{1}{3^3}+\dfrac{1}{4^3}+\cdots\right) - \dfrac 1 {2^3} \cdot \left( \dfrac 1 {1^3} + \dfrac 1 {2^3} + \dfrac 1 {3^3} + \cdots \right)}{\dfrac{1}{1^3}+\dfrac{1}{2^3}+\dfrac{1}{3^3}+\dfrac{1}{4^3}+ \cdots} \\[12pt]
= {} & \frac{ \left( 1 - \dfrac 1 {2^3} \right) \left( \dfrac{1}{1^3}+\dfrac{1}{2^3}+\dfrac{1}{3^3}+\dfrac{1}{4^3}+\cdots\right)}{\dfrac{1}{1^3}+\dfrac{1}{2^3}+\dfrac{1}{3^3}+\dfrac{1}{4^3}+ \cdots} \\[12pt]
= {} & 1 - \dfrac 1 {2^3}.
\end{align}